# TypeError: past must be a string or Buffer

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I'm trying to list all files in a specific folder using node.
Below is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dir = 'E:\\';
fs.readdir(dir,(err, files)=>{
    console.log(files);
    for (let ite in files) {
        var file_path = files[ite].toString();
        fs.appendFile('filelist.csv', file_path + ',' + fs.statSync(dir.concat(file_path).size) + "\n", (err)=>{
            if (err) {
            fs.writeFileSync('error.txt', err);
            console.log('The process is failed!!!');
            }
        })
    }

})
```

But I get errors like below:

```
fs.js:948
  binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
          ^

TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:948:11)
    at fs.readdir (D:\check_duplicate\check_duplicate.js:8:60)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: First of all you should review the SO guidelines on how to post questions. Secondly, you are getting a quite simple error so research it and share your work.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that here (you access size property of string which will be undefined)

```
fs.statSync(dir.concat(file_path).size)
```

this will evaluate to

```
fs.statSync(undefined)
```

I think you meant to do the following:

```
fs.statSync(dir.concat(file_path)).size
```